# C# - Moq - Object of mocked Interface is a proxy instead of the exposed class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to Mock `SqlConnection`, which essentially is `IDbConnection`.

For that I **prepare** my mock for my test:

`var dbConnectionMock = new Mock<IDbConnection>();`

`dbConnectionMock.Setup(x => x.CreateCommand()).Returns(new SqlCommand());`

`var repository = new XxxRepository(dbConnectionMock.Object);`

---

The **Constructor** of the repository sets this property:

`private IDbConnection Connection { get; set; }`

And then `Connection` is used when calling the Db.

`var command = Connection.CreateCommand();`

`command.Connection = Connection;` // here it fails, because Connection is the proxy type of `IDbConnection`, `IDbConnectionProxy`.

How can I avoid the use of the proxy?

All I wanna test is that `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` was called.

Comment: either abstract ado.net within your own object, or use an actual connection. trying to mock ado.net is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

Problem might be the use of `SqlConnection`, as its `Connection` property is of `SqlConnection` type. Try to return **mocked `IDbCommand`** instead:

```
var dbCommandMock = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
dbCommandMock.Setup(dbc => dbc.ExecuteNonQuery());
dbConnectionMock.Setup(dbc => dbc.CreateCommand()).Returns(dbCommandMock.Object);

// ...

dbCommandMock.VerifyAll();
```